# Problems upgrading from Vista to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

When upgrading from Vista to Windows 7 during the final stage computer makes a loud buzzing sound and freezes. Only way to stoop this is to turn the laptop off. Windows Upgrade Advisor says compatability is OK. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't upgrade the OS. Instead try installing the new OS into some other partition. You need to select "Custom Install" for the same.

After installing windows 7, you can format your drive holding Windows Vista. However, make sure to take all backups from the program files, downloads logs and App Data before deleting the previous version.